# Ruby .each block doesn't add up all objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason it seems like `.each` block iterate only once, when I write lets say 3 or 4 comments, `@total_comments` displays only 1, instead of 3 or 4.

The relationships are:

- user has many posts
- post has many comments

Can anybody help please?

controller

```
@total_comments = 0
@posts = current_user.posts

@posts.each do |post|
@comments = post.comments
@new_comments = @comments.count -@comments.where("created_at < ?",1.day.ago).count
@total_comments += @new_comments
end
```

view

```
<%= @total_comments %>
```

Comment: Surely that is more complex than it needs to be?

Comment: You could have a much simpler and faster version of this just by using a COUNT(*), JOIN, and GROUP BY statement in SQL, or by using the equivalent Rails helpers.

Comment: The problem here is that as stated above, you could do this much simpler.  This is a classic example of n+1 (if there are 10 posts, this will result in 11 queries against your database).  Try cleaning it up using the above suggestions.  Also, you don't really need to make `@comments`, `@old_comments` and `@new_comments` instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count of all comments you want something like this

```
@total_comments = Comment.count(
    :conditions => ["post.user_id = ? and comment.created_at >= ?", 
        current_user.id, 1.day.ago], 
    :include => :post
)
```

Although without knowing your data model it's difficult to say exactly.

As discussed with @m_x, a neater and more rails-3/ruby 1.9 esque version of above

```
@total_comments = Comment
                .joins( post:  :user )
                .where( users: {id: current_user.id} )
                .where( "created_at < ?", 1.day.ago )
                .count
```

Comment: Why not use `@post.user.comments`?

Comment: @RyanBigg We don't know the OP's data model - there are *many* possibilities - the point of my answer was to indicate you could do it using AR/SQL aggregate functions and not n + 1 queries.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead :

```
@total_comments = Comment
                    .joins( post:  :user )
                    .where( users: {id: current_user.id} )
                    .where( "comments.created_at < ?", 1.day.ago )
                    .count
```

**EDIT**

i definitely need some sleep. as @Ryan pointed out this is much simpler :

```
@total_comments = current_user.comments.where( "created_at < ?", 1.day.ago ).count
```

... but the OP has to add this to his `User` model :

```
has_many :comments, through: :posts
```

Comment: first thought that @Emma's answer was better, because i thought that `count` was some sort of `Array` method. [But i checked](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations) ans `count` called on a relation _does_ generate an SQL `COUNT()` query. I learned something tonight.

Comment: You're right it does! What I was trying to get at was to use a set of parameters to end up with a single SQL query, and not a n+1 queries with hard to follow logic. Swings and roundabouts.

Comment: indeed, i still think that using `joins` would be more appropriate that using `includes`. There's no need to eager-load the posts after all. feel free to edit your post if you agree.

Comment: I will edit as I do think yours is a neater example :) - though when using includes in a count, no eager loading occurs as no models are loaded at all.

Comment: in fact, it IS eager loaded : http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count

Comment: Hmm, I think the documentation is unclear. Eager loading can only apply when models are loaded, otherwise what else is there to load, eagerly or otherwise? I think what the documentation is referring to is the underlying mechanism by which you reference associations, which is the same as in eager loading, rather than that it is in some way (?) used. Of course, I might be wrong. Easy way to check: construct a test and view the generated SQL.

Comment: i checked with your solution, and seems you're right. The generated query uses a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, but does not load the records with another query. This is confusing.

Comment: Eager loading has nothing to do with join type, but only the loading of models. Join type has more to do with the type of association.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget to save you comments - some comments are not saved to database that's why you're loosing some of comments.

Also you could use **autosave** option to automatically save your variables every time when you're changing them.